# Decrypting with RSA encryption in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I created a public and private key using openssl in the cmd line of a linux machine using the following commands:

`openssl genrsa -out rsa_1024_priv.pem 1024`
`openssl rsa -pubout -in rsa_1024_priv.pem -out rsa_1024_pub.pem`

Now I want to be able to decrypt data in VB.NET that was already encrypted with the public key.

I am using the method found in [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#Examples) for decryption. I am trying to set the RSAParameters to pass in to the `RSADecrypt` method, but I'm not really sure what goes into each field.

Whenever I try running the code I get the following error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicExce
>   ption(Int32 hr)
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportKey(SafeProvHandle hCSP, Int32 k
>   eyNumber, CspProviderFlags flags, Object cspObject, SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(RSA
>   Parameters parameters)
>      at Decryptor.Module1.RSADecrypt(Byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInf
>   o, Boolean DoOAEPPadding) in C:\Users\yhorowitz\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects
>   \Decryptor\Module1.vb:line 30

The error is being thrown on this line `RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo)` in the `RSADecrypt` method

This is the code I have so far:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
    Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding

    Sub Main()
        Dim MyPrivateKey As String = "" 'Removed
        Dim MyPublicKey As String = "" 'Removed
        Dim MyModulus as String = "" 'Removed

        Dim DataToDecrypt() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String("CourNHBC55DgGtBZU6Ahtm0emywGi5hWo5/h9zD6A/NASKMpZ/A5GCU8G5TNTMgJQxVFsabbdeuNhf4VQzBuFqewuD8eD7MwpJvjmuPfrs7xcEzOrwbF549v0PHv/nfN+03winW6s3ecnv1dm0TctQgqsauEuvXu2PMVEFivqPo=")

        Dim params As RSAParameters = New RSAParameters()

        params.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(MyPublicKey)
        params.D = Convert.FromBase64String(MyPrivateKey)
        params.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(MyModulus)

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(RSADecrypt(DataToDecrypt, params, False)))
        Console.Read()
    End Sub

    Public Function RSADecrypt(ByVal DataToDecrypt() As Byte, ByVal RSAKeyInfo As RSAParameters, ByVal DoOAEPPadding As Boolean) As Byte()
        Try
            Dim decryptedData() As Byte
            'Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            Using RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024)
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo)
                decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding)
            End Using
            Return decryptedData
        Catch e As CryptographicException
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the most strict of senses, the RSA algorithm requires

- Public key (n (aka Modulus), e)
- Private key (n, d)

And some libraries, like OpenSSL, will work with just the (n, e, d) triplet.

But Windows CAPI (and probably Windows CNG) pretty much ignores `d`, because it's much more efficient to do RSA using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) (CRT).

So `RSACryptoServiceProvider` (and `RSACng` (net46+, netcoreapp10+), and `RSAOpenSsl` (netcoreapp10+)) all require a fully populated `RSAParameters` structure for private keys.

For public-only, you can set just `Modulus` and `Exponent`.

For private, you need to set all of the fields, and they must have the following characteristics:

- `Modulus[0]` must not be `0`.
- `D` and `Modulus` must be the same number of bytes.
- `E` is whatever it is, but `E[0]` must not be `0`.
- `P`, `Q`, `DP`, `DQ`, `InverseQ` must all be the same number of bytes, and that number must be exactly half the size of `Modulus` (round up, if it matters).

To line terms up from OpenSSL's RSA pretty-print to RSAParameters:

```
-----------------------------------
| OpenSSL         | RSAParameters |
-----------------------------------
| modulus         | Modulus       |
| publicExponent  | Exponent      |
| privateExponent | D             |
| prime1          | P             |
| prime2          | Q             |
| exponent1       | DP            |
| exponent2       | DQ            |
| coefficient     | InverseQ      |
-----------------------------------
```

For an example of converted data (on a key already disclosed as a test key), see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/193d663393b75f83a447a635523a6e84454d9482/src/Common/tests/System/Security/Cryptography/AlgorithmImplementations/RSA/TestData.cs#L179-L285, which is the same as this OpenSSL dump:

```
$ openssl rsa -in rsa1032.key -text -noout
Private-Key: (1032 bit)
modulus:
    00:bc:ac:b1:a5:34:9d:7b:35:a5:80:ac:3b:39:98:
    eb:15:eb:f9:00:ec:b3:29:bf:1f:75:71:7a:00:b2:
    19:9c:8a:18:d7:91:b5:92:b7:ec:52:bd:5a:f2:db:
    0d:3b:63:5f:05:95:75:3d:ff:7b:a7:c9:87:2d:bf:
    7e:32:26:de:f4:4a:07:ca:56:8d:10:17:99:2c:2b:
    41:bf:e5:ec:35:70:82:4c:f1:f4:b1:59:19:fe:d5:
    13:fd:a5:62:04:af:20:34:a2:d0:8f:f0:4c:2c:ca:
    49:d1:68:fa:03:fa:2f:a3:2f:cc:d3:48:4c:15:f0:
    a2:e5:46:7c:76:fc:76:0b:55:09
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    00:9e:59:25:e2:ec:6c:bb:4a:83:f3:a1:19:37:b6:
    e2:9e:8c:64:78:65:2f:dc:fa:9d:d1:78:82:97:70:
    e2:53:e2:07:05:6d:32:01:c8:41:1c:13:f5:ef:da:
    ee:99:08:46:68:ae:4e:2e:d1:6c:1b:9e:e4:c7:fd:
    6e:51:73:14:2d:c5:9f:c6:45:a4:c2:e6:65:5d:ac:
    e6:71:b3:00:de:0d:7b:b5:2d:68:a8:60:26:c1:8f:
    02:47:26:e7:71:bd:04:81:99:44:2f:03:42:70:96:
    58:ef:f6:4a:e4:2e:a4:17:32:47:ec:d2:4a:86:29:
    9e:8b:9d:11:52:00:02:c8:f5:f1
prime1:
    0e:15:30:0a:9d:34:ba:37:b6:bd:a8:31:bc:67:27:
    b2:f7:f6:d0:ef:b7:b3:3a:99:c9:af:28:cf:d6:25:
    e2:45:a5:4f:25:1b:78:4c:47:91:ad:a5:85:ad:b7:
    11:d9:30:0a:3d:52:b4:50:cc:30:7f:55:d3:1e:12:
    17:b9:ff:d7:45
prime2:
    0d:65:c6:0d:e8:b6:f5:4a:77:56:fd:1c:cb:a7:6c:
    e4:1e:f4:46:d0:24:03:1e:e9:c5:a4:09:31:b0:73:
    36:cf:ed:35:a8:ee:58:0e:19:db:85:92:cb:0f:26:
    6e:c6:90:28:eb:9e:98:e3:e8:4f:f1:a4:59:a8:a2:
    68:60:a6:10:f5
exponent1:
    0d:9d:b4:be:7e:73:0d:9d:72:a5:7b:2a:e3:73:85:
    71:c7:c8:2f:09:a7:be:b5:e9:1d:94:aa:cc:10:cc:
    be:33:02:7b:3c:70:8b:e6:8c:c8:30:71:ba:87:54:
    5b:00:78:2f:5e:4d:49:a4:59:58:86:b5:6f:93:42:
    81:08:48:72:55
exponent2:
    0c:f6:fb:dd:e1:e1:8b:25:70:af:21:69:88:3a:90:
    c9:80:9a:eb:1b:e8:7d:8c:a0:b4:bd:b4:97:fd:24:
    c1:5a:1d:36:dc:2f:29:cf:1b:7e:af:98:0a:20:b3:
    14:67:da:81:7e:e1:8f:1a:9d:69:1f:71:e7:c1:a4:
    c8:55:1e:df:31
coefficient:
    01:0c:e9:93:6e:96:fb:ad:f8:72:40:cc:41:9d:01:
    08:1b:b6:7c:98:1d:44:31:4e:58:58:3a:c7:fe:93:
    79:ea:02:72:e6:c4:c7:c1:46:38:e1:d5:ec:e7:84:
    0d:db:15:a1:2d:70:54:a4:18:f8:76:4f:a5:4c:e1:
    34:eb:d2:63:5e
```