# RSA Cryptography with raw keys, c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I have been given a 256 byte modulus ('n'), a 256 byte private exponent ('d') and a 3  byte {1,0,1} public exponent ('e').  I am trying to sign 32 bytes of data.

I have tried to create a new RSAParameters.

```
byte[] n = new byte[256]; //populated in my code 
byte[] d = new byte[256]; //populated in my code
byte[] e = new byte[]{1,0,1}; 
byte[] junkData = new byte[32]; //populated in my code

RSAParameters rsaParam = new RSAParameters();
rsaParam.Modulus = n;
rsaParam.Exponent = e;
rsaParam.D = d;
```

I then create a RSACrytoServiceProvider, import the parameters into it, and try to sign data.

```
var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
csp.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
csp.SignData(junkData, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
```

The problem is that the RSACryptoServiceProvider appears to be public only, and when I try to sign I receive a 'Keyset does not exist' Cryptography Exception.

Do I also need the P and Q elements to properly sign the data, or am I doing something that is obviously wrong?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: i suspect that the csp wants P & Q and np and nq to simplyfy sign and decrypt operations with the chinese remainder theorem ... saves a few cycles, but requires more than N, d and e

Comment: ... aaand of course i forgot to mention q_inv ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypting with RSA encryption in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098493/decrypting-with-rsa-encryption-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that the ImportParameters didn't throw (are you using Mono?).

RSACryptoServiceProvider (and all of the RSA implementations in .NET Framework and .NET Core) require a fully populated RSAParameters structure for private keys.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42117655/6535399 gives the answer in a bit more detail.

Comment: This looks to me like a duplicate to me. Am I wrong? Why did you provide a very similar answer again?

Comment: I agree it has a duplicate answer, but that the two questions discovered the problems by different means. Though, I guess being marked as dupe leaves the forwarding link...

Comment: If you go to the question where you left the original answer, you see that it links this question in the right panel right below the meta and global questions.

Comment: I am using .net 4.6 within Visual Studio on a Windows PC.  I didn't get any errors until I tried signing data.  The import was fine, albeit only a 'public' key.  Adding the rest of the terms provided the details to get a private key and allowed me to sign data as expected.