# How to encrypt and decrypt a string with manually set RSA parameters? Why RSACryptoServiceProvider is throwing?

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core, rsa

I'm trying to manually set the properties of a `RSAParameters`, but I'm getting all sorts of errors when I try to encrypt, decrypt or even instantiate the `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

If I set only the Exponent and the Modulus, I'm able to encrypt a message; but I when I try to decrypt it I get a    `Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Key does not exist`

If I set all the properties, I get a `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The specified RSA parameters are not valid; both Exponent and Modulus are required fields.'`

**My question is why? What's wrong with my parameters?**

I'm obviously **not** using random values for the fields; I copy-pasted their string representations from another project.

Below is the code I wrote, it's targeting .Net Core 2.1.
I updated it to include this [length restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098493/decrypting-with-rsa-encryption-in-vb-net/42117655#42117655)

```
namespace PlayingWithCryptography {
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Numerics;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    public static class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            var msg = "lol";
            var encodedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);

            var parameters = new RSAParameters();

            parameters.P = BigInteger.Parse("14299623962416399520070177382898895550795403345466153217470516082934737582776038882967213386204600674145392845853859217990626450972452084065728686565928113").ToByteArray();

            parameters.Q = BigInteger.Parse("7630979195970404721891201847792002125535401292779123937207447574596692788513647179235335529307251350570728407373705564708871762033017096809910315212884101").ToByteArray();

            parameters.D = BigInteger.Parse("46730330223584118622160180015036832148732986808519344675210555262940258739805766860224610646919605860206328024326703361630109888417839241959507572247284807035235569619173792292786907845791904955103601652822519121908367187885509270025388641700821735345222087940578381210879116823013776808975766851829020659073").ToByteArray();

            parameters.Modulus = BigInteger.Parse("109120132967399429278860960508995541528237502902798129123468757937266291492576446330739696001110603907230888610072655818825358503429057592827629436413108566029093628212635953836686562675849720620786279431090218017681061521755056710823876476444260558147179707119674283982419152118103759076030616683978566631413").ToByteArray();

            parameters.Exponent = BigInteger.Parse("65537").ToByteArray();

            parameters.DP = BigInteger.Parse("11141736698610418925078406669215087697114858422461871124661098818361832856659225315773346115219673296375487744032858798960485665997181641221483584094519937").ToByteArray();

            parameters.DQ = BigInteger.Parse("4886309137722172729208909250386672706991365415741885286554321031904881408516947737562153523770981322408725111241551398797744838697461929408240938369297973").ToByteArray();

            parameters.InverseQ = BigInteger.Parse("5610960212328996596431206032772162188356793727360507633581722789998709372832546447914318965787194031968482458122348411654607397146261039733584248408719418").ToByteArray();

            Console.WriteLine($"M[0]={parameters.Modulus[0]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"D.Length={parameters.D.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"M.Length={parameters.Modulus.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"E={parameters.Exponent[0]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"P.Length={ parameters.P.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Q.Length={ parameters.Q.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DP.Length={ parameters.DP.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DQ.Length={ parameters.DQ.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"InverseQ.Length={ parameters.InverseQ.Length}");

            // Adding zeros coz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098493/decrypting-with-rsa-encryption-in-vb-net/42117655#42117655
            parameters.D = new byte[] { 0 }.Concat(parameters.D).ToArray();
            parameters.DQ = new byte[] { 0 }.Concat(parameters.DQ).ToArray();
            parameters.InverseQ = new byte[] { 0 }.Concat(parameters.InverseQ).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"M[0]={parameters.Modulus[0]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"D.Length={parameters.D.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"M.Length={parameters.Modulus.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"E[0]={parameters.Exponent[0]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"P.Length={ parameters.P.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Q.Length={ parameters.Q.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DP.Length={ parameters.DP.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DQ.Length={ parameters.DQ.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"InverseQ.Length={ parameters.InverseQ.Length}");

            var csp = RSACryptoServiceProvider.Create();

            csp.ImportParameters(parameters);

            var encrypted = csp.Encrypt(
                  data: encodedMessage,
                  padding: RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
            var decrypted = csp.Decrypt(
                  data: encrypted,
                  padding: RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

            var decoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decrypted);
            Console.WriteLine(decoded);
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }

    }
}
```

**Answered** To anyone in a similar situation, please read (and vote) both James K Polk's answers and then the [answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415078/net-core-2-0-rsa-platformnotsupportedexception)

Comment: The `D` parameter is commonly called the decrypt exponent. You need it decrypt data. That's why we say RSA is an example of asymmetric cryptography: the asymmetry is that one key is used for encryption and a different key is used for decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to leave my other answer up for now, but I have reason to doubt the restrictions quoted therein. For the parameters in the question, my other answer suggests that `RSAParameters.P` must be exactly 64 bytes. However that can't possibly work, as the P in the question requires at least 65 bytes to represent.

Instead, I'll suggest you use the [`RSA.FromXMLString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring?view=netcore-2.1) method to import RSA public and private keys. That seems to be based on an external standard called [XML Signature Syntax and Processing Version 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/), and in particular [this section](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-RSAKeyValue) with further details [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-CryptoBinary). The basic idea is to encode the integers as big-endian byte arrays of minimal length -- no leading zeros -- and then base64-encode that.

Here is some lightly tested code to accomplish it. Note that C# and .NET are not my strong suit, so feel free to improve this. Note that, on my platform, OAEPSha1 was the only supported OAEP padding.

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace PlayingWithCryptography
{
    public static class ConvertToRSAParameters
    {

        public static string ConvertXML(BigInteger e, BigInteger n)
        {
            var xml = new StringBuilder();
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(n), "Modulus"));
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(e), "Exponent"));
            WrapTags(xml, "RSAKeyValue");
            return xml.ToString();
        }

        public static string ConvertXML(BigInteger e, BigInteger n, BigInteger p, BigInteger q,
                                            BigInteger d, BigInteger dp, BigInteger dq, BigInteger inverseQ)
        {
            var xml = new StringBuilder();
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(n), "Modulus"));
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(e), "Exponent"));
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(p), "P"));
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(q), "Q"));
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(d), "D"));
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(dp), "DP"));
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(dq), "DQ"));
            xml.AppendLine(WrapTags(BigToBase64(inverseQ), "InverseQ"));
            WrapTags(xml, "RSAKeyValue");
            return xml.ToString();

        }

        private static string BigToBase64(BigInteger val)
        {
            var valBytes = val.ToByteArray();
            int len = valBytes.Length;
            while (valBytes[len - 1] == 0)
            {
                --len;
                if (len == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Array.Resize(ref valBytes, len);
            Array.Reverse(valBytes);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(valBytes);
        }

        private static string WrapTags(string target, string tag)
        {
            return String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", tag, target);
        }

        private static StringBuilder WrapTags(StringBuilder target, string tag)
        {
            return target.Insert(0, String.Format("<{0}>", tag)).AppendFormat("</{0}>", tag);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var msg = "lol";
            var encodedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);

            Console.WriteLine();

            var publicRsa = RSA.Create();

            publicRsa.FromXmlString(
                ConvertToRSAParameters.ConvertXML(
                    BigInteger.Parse("65537"),
                    BigInteger.Parse("109120132967399429278860960508995541528237502902798129123468757937266291492576446330739696001110603907230888610072655818825358503429057592827629436413108566029093628212635953836686562675849720620786279431090218017681061521755056710823876476444260558147179707119674283982419152118103759076030616683978566631413")
                )
            );

            var privateRsa = RSA.Create();

            privateRsa.FromXmlString(
                ConvertToRSAParameters.ConvertXML(
                    BigInteger.Parse("65537"),
                    BigInteger.Parse("109120132967399429278860960508995541528237502902798129123468757937266291492576446330739696001110603907230888610072655818825358503429057592827629436413108566029093628212635953836686562675849720620786279431090218017681061521755056710823876476444260558147179707119674283982419152118103759076030616683978566631413"),
                    BigInteger.Parse("14299623962416399520070177382898895550795403345466153217470516082934737582776038882967213386204600674145392845853859217990626450972452084065728686565928113"),
                    BigInteger.Parse("7630979195970404721891201847792002125535401292779123937207447574596692788513647179235335529307251350570728407373705564708871762033017096809910315212884101"),
                    BigInteger.Parse("46730330223584118622160180015036832148732986808519344675210555262940258739805766860224610646919605860206328024326703361630109888417839241959507572247284807035235569619173792292786907845791904955103601652822519121908367187885509270025388641700821735345222087940578381210879116823013776808975766851829020659073"),
                    BigInteger.Parse("11141736698610418925078406669215087697114858422461871124661098818361832856659225315773346115219673296375487744032858798960485665997181641221483584094519937"),
                    BigInteger.Parse("4886309137722172729208909250386672706991365415741885286554321031904881408516947737562153523770981322408725111241551398797744838697461929408240938369297973"),
                    BigInteger.Parse("5610960212328996596431206032772162188356793727360507633581722789998709372832546447914318965787194031968482458122348411654607397146261039733584248408719418")
                )
            );

            var encrypted = publicRsa.Encrypt(
                  data: encodedMessage,
                  padding: RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
            var decrypted = privateRsa.Decrypt(
                  data: encrypted,
                  padding: RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);

            var decoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decrypted);
           Console.WriteLine(decoded);
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this won't work. https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/874
But complementing your answer with this, worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415078/net-core-2-0-rsa-platformnotsupportedexception

I'm going to be honest, I never had so much pain with C# before. I'm feeling in C++ land. Thank you much James,  I wish I could give you 500 points.

Comment: Ugh, what a nightmare. I went by the Microsoft docs which indicated support for .NET Core 2.0 and 2.1. It's possible the other answer works if you ignore the restriction the size of P has to be exactly half the size of the modulus. I don't really know.

Comment: The size restriction isn’t .NET, it’s CAPI. The only size input into the blob is the KeySize, everything else then gets derived offsets.

Comment: @bartonjs: So, can it work with a 128 byte modulus and 65 byte P?

Answer (score 3):

The details of what the fields of [`RSAParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters?view=netframework-4.7.1) must look like are given at the bottom of the page in the Feedback section by user bartonjs (who is also a stackoverflow user of the same name). Here is a copy of his comment:

The full rules of the arrays for RSAParameters values are as follows:

- Modulus: The unsigned big-endian representation of the RSA modulus
  value. Modulus[0] must not have the value 0x00.
- Exponent: The unsigned big-endian representation of the RSA public exponent value.  Exponent[0] must not have the value 0x00.

The other fields must either all be null (public key parameters), or all non-null (private key parameters). When the values are non-null:

- D: The unsigned big-endian representation of the RSA private exponent value. This array must be equal in length to the length of the Modulus value, inserting 0x00-value bytes at low indexes as necessary.
- P: The unsigned big-endian representation of the RSA prime p. This array must be equal in length to half of the length of the Modulus value (round up if necessary), inserting 0x00-value bytes at low
  indexes as necessary.
- Q: The unsigned big-endian representation of the RSA prime q. This array must be equal in length to half of the length of the Modulus value (round up if necessary), inserting 0x00-value bytes at low indexes as necessary.
  DP: The unsigned big-endian representation of the RSA CRT parameter dp. This array must be equal in length to half of the length of the Modulus value (round up if necessary), inserting 0x00-value bytes at low indexes as necessary.
- DQ: The unsigned big-endian representation of the RSA CRT parameter dq. This array must be equal in length to half of the length of the Modulus value (round up if necessary), inserting 0x00-value bytes at low indexes as necessary.
- InverseQ: The unsigned big-endian representation of the RSA CRT parameter qInverse. This array must be equal in length to half of the length of the Modulus value (round up if necessary), inserting 0x00-value bytes at low indexes as necessary.

Example: For a RSA key with a KeySize value of 2056 and having the standard public exponent value 0x010001, the array lengths are:

Public Key:

- Modulus: 257 bytes
- Exponent: 3 bytes
- D, P, Q, DP, DQ, InverseQ: null
  values.

Private Key:

- Modulus: 257 bytes
- Exponent: 3 bytes
- D: 257 bytes
- P: 129 bytes
- Q: 129 bytes
- DP: 129 bytes
- DQ: 129 bytes
- InverseQ: 129 bytes

Note that `BigInteger.ToByteArray()` returns the little-endian representation. This must be reversed to get the big-endian representation required by `RSAParameters`.

Comment: Jesus Christ, in the FEEDBACK section? Not sure if that solves my problems (will test and come back), but THANK YOU for the link. I'm thinking sure it's a endianness issue.

Comment: LOL, my reaction exactly.